# Python PSFTP No hostkey for host x.x.x.x found

Tags: python-3.x, psftp, known-hosts

I am running Python 3.6.8 on RHEL 8

I am trying to connect to sftp on another server using this
#!/usr/bin/env python

```
import pysftp

myHostname = I.I.I.I
myport = PPPP
myUsername = xxx
myPassword = xxx

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts(knownhosts='/home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts')

with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, port=myport, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
```

I get this error:

```
Exception has occurred: SSHException
No hostkey for host I.I.I.I found.
  File "/home/xxxx/python/xxxxy", line 16, in <module>
    with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, port=myport, username=myUsername, 
password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
```

But when I query cnopts.hostkeys I find the server listed

```
[I.I.I.I]:PPPP
```

the IP Address found in cnopts is the same IP Address in the SFTP command

if I insert this line into my script:

```
cnopts.hostkeys = None
```

I connect fine to the far end

This points that connectivity and authentication is working fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: really weird...had the same issue, but I could connect with FileZilla / cyberduck and MacOs `sftp` cli  ... then I tried to connect to another server (with python) and at some point it worked... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯